# Derangements relative to multiple arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

Literature is rife with results on classical derangements, that is, permutations on a set of elements that leave no element fixed. Generalizations also abound. In ['Matchings, Derangements, Rencontres'](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689812?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), we have a pretty good description of the numbers $D(n,k,r)$ of $k$-permutations on $n$ elements that leave all but $r$ elements fixed. $q$- and even [$p,q$- analogues](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00026-009-0010-4) of derangement numbers have been studied.

I am interested in another generalization of derangements. A classical derangement leaves no element of **one** given arrangement fixed. Given $k$ arrangements $\sigma_i$ $(1 \leq i \leq k)$, of the same $n$ elements, a *$k$-derangement* is a permutation $\rho$ (of the $n$ elements) that at no point coincides with any $\sigma_i$. In particular, a $1$-derangement is a classical derangement.

The only source I could find discussing this topic is [this one](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath430.htm). While certainly enlightening, I would like to know how to actually, theoretically, calculate the number $D(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_k)$ of $k$-derangements. Any ideas, or references?

Comment: It seems like you can still apply inclusion-exclusion in a reasonable way, so long as you know where the arrangements agree and disagree.

Comment: @TokenToucan Even with relatively simple $\sigma$'s, I've had difficulty finding a sensible pattern. I've been working with $\sigma_1 = 1$ $2$ $\dots$ $n$ and $\sigma_i$ obtained from $\sigma_1$ by $(i-1)$ right shifts.

Comment: I was thinking about counting over the set of forbidden positions based on the permutations - in the $n=2$ case it did not seem too difficult, but maybe I am missing something. It seems like it would extend to larger $n$ in a fairly direct way (but not in a general form)

Comment: @TokenToucan $n=2$ is way too simple. The only possible arrangements being $1$ $2$ and $2$ $1$ makes it rather trivial. Trying out a value of, say, $n=10$ should make things more complicated.

Comment: As in $n$ different permutations.

Comment: @TokenToucan Oh, right. For $2$ different permutations (of say$10$ elements) I already find it troublesome.

Comment: Let $P_i$ be the property that $i$ is not in a forbidden position, and it seems to fall right out of inclusion-exclusion. Probably there will be nicer forms of it depending on the distribution of the sizes of the $P_i$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36563/discussion-between-fimpellizieri-and-tokentoucan).

Comment: I was playing around with $k=2$ such permutations, and stumbled across this thread. I was curious about generating one of the elements of said $D(\sigma_1, \sigma_2)$ efficiently. Any new insights came out of your chat?

Comment: I don't even remember to be honest. I do remember we couldn't find a good answer for this question.